# Simple 2d program working with colors, buttons, and if statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, game-center

There are 3 buttons present. Clicking a button will change its color. The task here is to match every color of the buttons to a shade of green. Now, I have the buttons programmed to cycle through 4 colors, the same palette. It works, of course.

What I want to implement now is, to make a text appear once all the buttons match colors. I'm working on Unity and the c# script is on Visual Studio.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;     

 public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] int count = 0;
        [SerializeField] Color[] colorArray;
       public void button ()
        {
            if(count < colorArray.Length)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(colorArray[count].r, colorArray[count].g, colorArray[count].b);
                if(count == colorArray.Length - 1)
                {
                    count = -1;
                }
                count += 1;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `button` method can be simplified a lot.

And then I would use a callback that checks your colors everytime one of the buttons was pressed:

```
public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int count = 0;
    [SerializeField] Color[] colorArray;

    [SerializeField] private Image _image;

    public Color CurrentColor => _image.color;

    public event Action OnChangedColor;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_image) _image = GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    public void button ()
    {
        var count = (count + 1) % colorArray.Length;
        var nextColor = colorArray[Count];

        _image.color = nextColor;

        OnChangedColor?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And now in a central controller script you have references to all your buttons `ChangeColor` components and their according target `Color` like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class ButtonColorPair
{
    public ChangeColor changeColor;
    public Color targetColor;

    // Returns true if a ChangeColor is referenced and the colors are matching
    public bool IsMatching => changeColor && changeColor.CurrentColor == tatgetColor;
}

public class ColorChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ButtonColorPair[] buttonColorPairs;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Register a callback which is called every time one of the buttons
        // has changed the color
        foreach(var pair in buttonColorPairs)
        {
            // It is save to remove a callback even if it wasn't added before
            // but it makes sure there is only one single callback 
            pair.changeColor.OnChangedColor -= HandleChangedColor;
            pair.changeColor.OnChangedColor += HandleChangedColor;

            // Here you would also set the targetColor if you want to do it via code e.g. like
            pair.targetColor = Color.green;
            // or to be save e.g. pick a random value from the color array etc

            // Maybe this class would even be responsible for telling the buttons which colors are 
            // available at all
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // As a good practice always remove callbacks as soon as you don't need them anymore
        foreach(var pair in buttonColorPairs)
        {
            pair.changeColor.OnChangedColor -= HandleChangedColor;
        }
    }

    // Finally check if the color matches for all buttons everytime one of them was changed
    private void HandleChangedColor ()
    {
        // This is Linq and require "using System.Linq;" on top of your file
        if(buttonColorPairs.All(p => p.IsMatching)
        {
            Debug.Log("All buttons are matching their target color");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Nope not all matching yet");
        }
        // it basically equals doing something like
        //bool allMatch = true;
        //foreach(var p in buttonColorPairs)
        //{
        //    if(!p.IsMatching) 
        //    {
        //        allMatch = false;
        //        break;
        //    }
        //}
        //if(allMatch)
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("All buttons are matching their target color");
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("Nope not all matching yet");
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance btw. If I may ask, is the second script like a separate one?

Comment: It says that the public event "Action" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: As you can see the second script is a separate `MonoBehaviour` that has to be on one persistent controller `GameObject` in your scene yes. And [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action) is in the namespace `System` so yes you should have `using System;` on top of your file or use explicitly `public event System.Action ...`